# SQL partition with running totals

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am trying to figure out a way to solve the following problem:

Each month users purchase x $ amount of items. For every $2500 they purchase they earn one gift card. If in a given month they do not purchase $2500 worth of items, the $ amount purchased is rolled over to the next month and included in the amount purchased total.

For example:
January - amount purchased $200. This is less than $2500, so, $200 rolled over to February
February - amount purchased $600. $600 + $200 is less than $2500, so, $800 is rolled over to March.
March - amount purchased $1900. So, $1900 + $800 = $2700. 1 gift card earned and $200 rolled over to April.

I would like to be able to calculate the gift cards earned for each month.

Thanks

My table has the following columns : FiscalYear, FiscalMonth, Customer, AmountPurchased.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Total Gift Cards this month
,FLOOR
(
    ISNULL
    (
        SUM(AmountPurchased) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY FiscalYear, FiscalMonth)
        ,0
    ) / 2500
)
-- subtract Total Gift Cards last month
-
FLOOR
(
    ISNULL
    (
        SUM(AmountPurchased) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer
            ORDER BY FiscalYear, FiscalMonth ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
        ,0
    ) / 2500
) AS GiftCardsThisMonth
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed! Thanks!